# Can I, How do I, call a pelican plugin from a markdown page?

Tags: markdown, jsfiddle, pelican

I've installed the pelican jsfiddle plugin and from a restructured text page, I can "call it" by

```
.. jsfiddle FIDDLEID
```

Doing so embeds the fiddle into the pelican page.

How would I do this using a markdown page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just took a look at the [source code](https://github.com/if1live/pelican-jsfiddle) for that plugin and it appears that Markdown is not supported. In other words, the plugin authors only included support for ReST, but not Markdown. And understandably so. They used a ReST "directive" and Markdown has not concept of directives or anything like them.

That said, Pelican uses Python-Markdown for parsing Markdown, which has a very extensive [Extension API](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/api.html). I did a quick search and don't see that anyone has created a jsfiddle extension for Python-Markdown yet, but it wouldn't be terribly difficult to do (see a [tutorial here](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/wiki/Tutorial:-Writing-Extensions-for-Python-Markdown)). If you are looking for any pre-existing syntax, I did find [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507944/Extending-Markdown-MarkdownSharp-for-jsFiddle-embe.aspx) which was part of a different Markdown implementation. It uses `$[FIDDLEID]` borrowing from the image syntax (using a `$` instead of `!`). Of course, as that is non-standard Markdown it will not work if you migrate to another Markdown implementation in the future. A common solution to that problem in the Markdown world it to implement something inside an HTML comment instead of some special custom syntax. Perhaps `<!-- $fiddle:FIDDLEID -->`. Then if migrated to another Markdown implementation, the comment would simply be ignored and nothing would break. Either way, actually building such an extension is beyond the scope of this answer. Of course, if you attempt to build it and run into issues, those specific issues may be separate questions of their own.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive research into this! One reason I would not write an extension is that by the time I implemented something inside an html comment, might as just include the html to embed the fiddle itself.